# Что за непонятная ошибка curl?

Tags: php, yii2, curl

пытаюсь в yii2 спарсить сайты партнеров на тему есть ли товар в наличии организовывал таким методом

```
public function haveParse($goods){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $goods->url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
        {
            $out= curl_error($ch);
        }else{
            $out=curl_exec($ch);
        }
        return $out;
    }
```

приходит следующее `boolean true`
при этом

```
 `var_dump($goods->url)==string 'http://xn----7sblaeg7cgj4a.com.ua/ve6rhnjaja-odejda/3339-palto-frak.html'`
```

если вот здесь `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $goods->url);` заменить на

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://xn----7sblaeg7cgj4a.com.ua/ve6rhnjaja-odejda/3339-palto-frak.html');
```

страница приходит полностью. Не подскажите в чем проблема.

Comment: описание `curl_exec` и тип возвращаемого результата читали? _зы, почему у вас в одном месте $goods->url а в другом просто $url_

Comment: @teran   при наличии `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` вот это  `return curl_exec($ch);` возвращает `string ''`

Comment: два раза подряд `curl_exec` не нужно (в условии `if()` и в теле `else`). Сразу положите в $out и проверяете только переменную.

Comment: обратите внимание, что при открытии адреса приходит 301й редирект

Comment: возвращает `string ''` по той причине, что редирект контента не имеет, а если опцию поставите нужную, то проследует за редиректом и вернет страницу.

Comment: Вообще для yii2 есть такое - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient

Comment: @Pa3Py6aka для Yii2  много чего есть ;)

Comment: @Sergalas так почему не использовать?))

Comment: @Pa3Py6aka у cUrl есть встроенные варианты перевода в строку и потом порегулярке быстрее будет чем класс вызывать и шелкать по его методам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не может такого быть, что вы описываете. А может только то, что написано в доках:

Возвращает **TRUE** в случае успешного завершения или **FALSE** в случае возникновения ошибки.

**Однако**, если установлена опция **CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER**, при успешном завершении будет возвращен результат, а при неудаче - **FALSE**.

Уверен, что вы просто чего-то недоговариваете.

---

пробовать надо так:

```
public function haveParse($goods){
    //$url = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $goods->url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    if(($out = curl_exec($ch)) === false)
        $out= curl_error($ch);

    return $out;
}
```

Comment: Вот смысл мне это делать ? Мой код выглядит вот так `public function haveParse($goods){
        $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $goods->url);     $out=curl_exec($ch);
        return $out;
    }` где goods это AR модель

Comment: @Sergalas `Вот смысл мне это делать ?  Мой код выглядит вот так` — ну да, ну да... в итоге ты обновил вопрос где есть `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`........ а до этого его там не было и тут в комменте нет......в итоге я был прав

Comment: в общем не это решило проблему, а связка из `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` без обид, извини что не полностью выложил код (но он был за комментирован и выкладывать его я думал что не суть)

Comment: @Sergalas `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` могло решить проблему только в случае, если с запрашиваемой страницы был редирект на другую, однако у тебя в условии было сказано, что с `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://xn----7sblaeg7cgj4a.com.ua/ve6rhnjaja-odejda/3339-palto-frak.html');` страница приходит полностью...... что явно не подразумевает никакие редиректы.....в общем что-то ты вечно утаиваешь в вопросах что в итоге ответ получается совсем не на то, какую проблему ты решаешь в итоге...